# javascript : Detecting result of a logical OR condition

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

Is there a built-in way to detect which half of a logical or within a conditional is true?

```
// foo would return true or false    
if (thing1 === "3" || thing2 === foo()) {
     // do something if thing1 is 3
     // do something different if thing2 is true    
};
```

Or should I just use two nested if blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two if blocks. There's no built-in way to do this.

Also if `foo()` returns a true or false, you don't need `thing2 === foo()` and the semicolon at the end is extraneous.

```
if (thing1 === "3") {
     // do something 
} else if (foo()) {
     // do something else
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: To ask if `foo()` is true or false is not the same as asking if `thing2 === foo()`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about "nested" part but usually it is done simply as:

```
if (thing1 === "3") {
     // do something if thing1 is 3
} else if (thing2 === foo()) {
    // do something different if thing2 is true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Not clubbing it together :

```
if (thing1 === "3") {

     // do something if thing1 is 3
}
else if(thing2 === foo()) {

     // do something different if thing2 is 'equal to return value of foo()'
}
```

Nested won't work anyway, since it's an **or** condition.

Answer (score 1):

use of `if` ans `elseif` is a good option

```
if ("3" === thing1) {
 // do something if thing1 is 3 
} else if (thing2  === foo()) {
 // do something different if thing2 is true
}
```